# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable em função CHOICE em 2D Lista Python

Tags: funções, python-2.7

Possuo o código abaixo e não consigo fazê-lo funcionar. Pois, preciso que um vetor da minha lista 2D seja escolhido aleatoriamente com a função CHOICE e efetue a soma dos valores que são menores que 85.0 e subtraia os valores quando for maior. Porém, ocorre o seguinte erro:

> "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable".

```
def escolher():
    from random import choice
    a = choice([[10.00,90.00,30.00,40.00],[50.00,60.00,90.00,80.00]])
    fitness_1_temp = 0
    for i in a:
        for j in i:
            if j <= 85.0:
                fitness_1_temp += j
            else:
                fitness_1_temp -= j
    return fitness_1_temp

print (escolher())
```

Onde estou errando?

Desde já grato pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from random import choice

def escolher():
    a = choice([[10.00,90.00,30.00,40.00],[50.00,60.00,90.00,80.00]])
    fitness_1_temp = 0
    for i in a:
        for j in i:
#---------------^^^
            if j <= 85.0:
                fitness_1_temp += j
            else:
                fitness_1_temp -= j
    return fitness_1_temp

print (escolher())
```

Veja no código acima, a parte destacada pelo comentário. Você está tentando iterar sobre um valor do tipo `float`. Aliás, nem tem muito sentido fazer os dois `loop`, apenas um é capaz de resolver a soma.

Digamos que `choice` retornou a primeira lista:

```
a = [10.00,90.00,30.00,40.00]
```

Fazendo a iteração `for i in a`, `i` possuirá os valores 10.0, 90.0, 30.0 e 40.0, dependendo da iteração corrente. A partir deste valor, já pode fazer a operação:

```
fitness_1_temp = (fitness_1_temp+i) if i <= 85.0 else (fitness_1_temp-i)
```

> Para os exemplos dados, será retornado -10.0 quando a primeira lista for considerada ou 100.0 quando a segunda.

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Fwax/1), no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/beQZAH), e no [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/acwoss/919679608e0f5da804f48d99a46e0d0c).

#### Solução alternativa

Quando desejamos reduzir uma lista para um único valor, podemos utilizar a operação `reduce`. No Python 2, `reduce` é uma *built-in function*, enquanto no Python 3 ela foi incorporada no módulo `functools`. Ambas possuem o mesmo formato:

```
reduce(function, iterable[, initializer])
```

No Python 2:

```
from random import choice

def escolher():
    a = choice([[10.00,90.00,30.00,40.00],[50.00,60.00,90.00,80.00]])
    fitness_1_temp = reduce(lambda x, y: (x+y) if y <= 85.0 else (x-y), a, 0)
    return fitness_1_temp

print (escolher())
```

No Python 3:

```
from random import choice
from functools import reduce

def escolher():
    a = choice([[10.00,90.00,30.00,40.00],[50.00,60.00,90.00,80.00]])
    fitness_1_temp = reduce(lambda x, y: (x+y) if y <= 85.0 else (x-y), a, 0)
    return fitness_1_temp

print (escolher())
```

Mesma solução, apenas é necessário importar a função do módulo `functools`.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente amigo. Muito Obrigado!

Comment: @Danilo, adicionei uma solução alternativa utilizando a função `reduce`. Dê uma olhada, vale a pena.

Comment: Eu vi a sua solução com reduce e está magnífica. Você me ajudou imensamente. Você nem tem ideia! Um forte abraço amigo.